# how to correct auto-complete div which is rolling behind an input tag

Tags: css, ajax, autocomplete

[image: this is what i mean]

auto-complete div is linked with the first input but the div is rolling behind the second input.how do i correct the problem ?

```
#suggesstion_box{
    position: absolute;
    left: 163px;
    top: 25px;
    border: 1px solid #222;
    width: 164px;
    background-color: white;
    cursor: default;
}
```

this is the css

Comment: Give z-index to this css rule ( eg : z-index:10;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give z-index to #suggesstion_box

```
#suggesstion_box{
z-index:9;    
position: absolute;
    left: 163px;
    top: 25px;
    border: 1px solid #222;
    width: 164px;
    background-color: white;
    cursor: default;
}
```